# codeigniter get directory info in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm essentially having difficulty pass dynamic variables to a view.

I have php functions as the following:

```
public function scandir_recursive($directory, $filter=FALSE)
{
 // if the path has a slash at the end we remove it here
 if(substr($directory,-1) == '/')
 {
     $directory = substr($directory,0,-1);
 }

 // if the path is not valid or is not a directory ...
 if(!file_exists($directory) || !is_dir($directory))
 {
     // ... we return false and exit the function
     return FALSE;

 // ... else if the path is readable
 }elseif(is_readable($directory))
 {
     // initialize directory tree variable
     $directory_tree = array();

     // we open the directory
     $directory_list = opendir($directory);

     // and scan through the items inside
     while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($directory_list)))
     {
         // if the filepointer is not the current directory
         // or the parent directory
         if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
         {
             // we build the new path to scan
             $path = $directory.'/'.$file;

             // if the path is readable
             if(is_readable($path))
             {
                 // we split the new path by directories
                 $subdirectories = explode('/',$path);

                 // if the new path is a directory
                 if(is_dir($path))
                 {
                     // add the directory details to the file list
                     $directory_tree[] = array(
                         'path'    => $path,
                         'name'    => end($subdirectories),
                         'kind'    => 'directory',

                         // we scan the new path by calling this function
                         'content' => scandir_recursive($path, $filter));

                 // if the new path is a file
                 }elseif(is_file($path))
                 {
                     // get the file extension by taking everything after the last dot
                     $extension = end(explode('.',end($subdirectories)));

                     // if there is no filter set or the filter is set and matches
                     if($filter === FALSE || $filter == $extension)
                     {
                         // add the file details to the file list
                         $directory_tree[] = array(
                             'path'      => $path,
                             'name'      => end($subdirectories),
                             'extension' => $extension,
                             'size'      => filesize($path),
                             'kind'      => 'file');
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     // close the directory
     closedir($directory_list);

     // return file list
     return $directory_tree;

// if the path is not readable ...
 }else{
     // ... we return false
     return FALSE;
    }
}
    </code>
```

I need to make such a function operable in the sense I can echo the data retrieved from the directories recursively and pass this data to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller do the following:

```
$data['directory_tree'] = scandir_recursive($directory);
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

In the view you can access the variable like this:

```
echo $directory_tree['path'];
```

Comment: hi Yah, ok so in my controller when I do $data['directory_tree'] = scandir_recursive($directory);
$this->load->view('test_view', $data); I get the error scandir_recursive undefined but it is defined. Now if I do this: $directory = '/uploads';

     $this->data['directory_tree'] = $this->scandir_recursive($directory, false);

     $this->load->view('test_view',$this->data); Then I don't get the error anymore but my output is nothing. Also in the codeigniter guide there is one example of a similar logical scenario but using static variables. So I wasn't even entirely sure dynamic was feasible.

Comment: Where is the cope of the function `scandir_recursive`? in the controller?

Comment: it's located in the index function. Ever since I had started trying to pass dynamic variables I have been getting atypical results in output as the one I had mentioned.

Comment: I had var_dump scandir_recursive and the function is working just fine outputting file info and directories recursively however when I try to echo such information to admin users I get blank output hence just whitespace. Also I am thinking internally for codeigniter $this special variable loads native functions automatically because CI_loader is called upon but you must use $this once again if the function isn't native to CI. Let me know what you think if this makes sense why it must be $this->scandir_recursive($directory).

Comment: So yes to clarify again, the function scandir_recursive is in the Controller. It is located within the index function which is located in the Controller.

Comment: You should place the function inside the controller class but outside of the index function, as a separate function. Afterwards you call it with the `$this` addition: `$data['directory_tree'] = $this->scandir_recursive($directory);` because its a member of the current class. `$this` holds your class which is an extension of the `CI_Controller`. The `CI_Controller` holds a lot more information in order for the framework to work properly. It doesn't no affect the performance or results of your functions.

Comment: Hi Yan, sorry for the misunderstanding. The function is in fact outside of index function but is being loaded in the index function. Example:public function index()
{

$data['directory_tree'] = $this->scandir_recursive($directory);
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);

}

Comment: In that case the issue is within the recursive function and not the framework. However this is out of scope for this question. I recommend asking a new question about the working of the recursive function and not the framework to get the relevant answers.

Comment: Yes good idea. Also thanks for your insightful responses. I still going to have to experiment some more with passing dynamic variables to view. I have directory_map working recursively but not yet to the extent I would like however I might need to extend it in order to get further recursion. I'm not sure and will post probably as another question. However at the moment I getting a odd error from renaming a sub-dir which I am going to post as a question. Anyhow your awesome Yan. :)